# MachineKey.Encode output is hex how do i set it do base64?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to match the viewstate encryption in my code, my issue is that the output of MachineKey.Encode is hex encoded and not base64 encoded. My code is:

```
        var plaintextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello");
        var encryptedValue = MachineKey.Encode(plaintextBytes, MachineKeyProtection.All);
        EncryptedData.Text = encryptedValue;

        var decryptedBytes = MachineKey.Decode(encryptedValue, MachineKeyProtection.All);
        DecryptedData.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
```

Do you have any idea how i can make that code output a base64 encoded string just like the viewstate data is encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

First off, consider using MachineKey.Protect and .Unprotect, as Encode and Decode are obsolete.

Protect returns a byte[], which you can just pass to Convert.ToBase64String

```
 byte[] encryptedValue = MachineKey.Protect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello"), "Some reason or another");
 string encryptedUTF8 = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedValue);
```

Comment: I know that Encode/Decode are obsolete but that is for .net 4.5, in .net 4.0 they are the only way to do this and that's the only version I can use at this time.